# Changing a files contents in git history

Tags: git, rebase

I need to modify the contents of a file in a commit from 500 commits ago.  So far I've tried an interactive rebase session and a git filter-branch without much luck.

My rebase appeared to be going well but the line in the file I changed creates a conflict on every subsequent pick from the rebase resulting in me having to resolve over 500 merge conflicts that are quite literally all the same thing.  (Perhaps I'm not doing something right here)

I also tried :

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter "echo mytextIwanttoinsert > My/file/path" -- --all
```

This ran for quite a while and in the end did not seem to have any effect.

What is the best strategy for this?  Is it a git filter-branch?  Is there something I'm doing wrong that is preventing that change from happening?

Comment: Sorry, I am not strong in git, but why not create new git commit for change what you want?

Comment: `git filter-branch ...` with a script which will resolve conflicts if you give a hint to it how to do such. Or resolve as many conflicts as needed manually. If it's **published** repository (note the difference to the *public* one) it's highly not recommended to do. Just do fix on top in that case.

Comment: I'm sure you don't need to change a file 500 commits ago. Also, you cannot do that. You can remove the commit and create another one.

Answer (score 2):

As several other people mentioned in comments and answers : the result of what you are asking is to delete all commits in your history and create new ones, which will impact people who cloned your repo (if any).

---

The `git filter-branch` command you posted works on my system, and correctly replaces the content of target file in all commits.

If you need more assistance : please give more details about what doesn't work.

---

Regarding `git rebase` and repeated conflict resolutions :

to have git automatically reapply a resolution you validated once when it meets exactly the same conflict, you can turn `git rerere` on :

```
git config --global rerere.enabled true
```

This feature is mostly a passive feature : you just turn it on, and from then on, when a conflict which you previously resolved re-appears, git will automatically apply the same patch as your initial resolution.

You can read the doc at [this link](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rerere), the [discussion](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rerere#_discussion) section gives a description of how it works.

Comment: DIdn't know about git filter-branch. Neither about rerere.enabled true. +1

Comment: Hey thanks for getting back to me and trying this.  Yes I'm not sure why it didn't work my side.  When I say didn't work I mean it didn't replace the contents of the file...

Comment: I guess the good thing is I know its the right concept so I can spend more time there...

Answer (score 0):

Normally you do not need to do such a think, or at least, I wonder why you would need to do something like that.

Here is a possible solution (there are probably loads of solutions as always in `git`).

Say you have a branch `master` on which you performed the following actions:

```
git touch myFile
git add myFile
git commit -m "First commit. A file myFile added."

# write "Line 1" on the first line of myFile
git add myFile
git commit -m "Line 1 added to myFile."

# write "Line 3" on the second line (note we forgot Line 2)
git add myFile
git commit -m "Line 3 added to myFile."

# and a last time with "Line 4"
git add myFile
git commit -m "Line 4 added to myFile."
```

Now, you cannot change a commit. But you can sort of replace a commit by another one. In this example, we want to remove the commit where we added `Line 3` and replace it by a commit in which we add `Line 2` and `Line 3`. This can be done as follows:

```
git checkout -b commits_to_recover # a branch with origin at the commit where we added "Line 4"
git reset --hard HEAD~2 # go back to the commit where we added Line 1
# myFile has now only "Line 1". Add "Line 2" and "Line 3". Then:
git add myFile
git commit -m "Line 2 and Line 3 added."
```

Now we only need to merge the branch `commits_to_recover` on `master`. You could rebase `commits_to_recover` on `master` first before doing the merge. You'll have to resolve conflicts of course.

```
git checkout commits_to_recover
git rebase master # and solve conflicts
git checkout master
git merge commits_to_recover
```

You could skip the rebase part and simply do:

```
# we are on master
git merge commits_to_recover # and solve conflicts
```

If the result is as desired, you can remove branch `commits_to_recover` and push `master` on the remote:

```
git branch -d commits_to_recover
git push -f origin master
```

Note: you could also `git cherry-pick` the commit of `Line 4` on `master` instead of using the `commits_to_recover` strategy.